# data reader assosiated with connection which must be closed mistake

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I have this bizarre mistake which I can't find a solution yet. I have a function which I envoke every time when I have to insert data in database. And its actually working because when i check the database entries they are actually there.

However I have this annoying mistake "There is already an open data reader assosiated with connection which must be closed". and I can't find a way to get read of it.

This is the function:

```
Sub InputDataValues(ByVal StrQwery As String)
    Try
        myconn.Open()
        Dim stquery As String = StrQwery
        Dim smd As MySqlCommand
        smd = New MySqlCommand(stquery, myconn)
        smd.ExecuteReader()

        smd.ExecuteReader().Close()//I added this when I wanted to get rid if the mistake
        myconn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim ErrorMessage As String = "alert('" & ex.Message.ToString() & "');"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", ErrorMessage, True)
        myconn.Close()
    End Try
    myconn.Close()
End Sub
```

And this is how I call it several times down in the code:

```
InputDataValues(StrQwery)
```

If anyone cam give me a hint I will be most grateful.

This is how it look when i changed it to ExecuteNonQuery

```
Sub InputDataValues(ByVal StrQwery As String)
    Try
        myconn.Open()
        Dim stquery As String = StrQwery
        Dim retValue As Integer
        Dim smd As MySqlCommand
        smd = New MySqlCommand(stquery, myconn)
        retValue = smd.EndExecuteNonQuery()

        myconn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim ErrorMessage As String = "alert('" & ex.Message.ToString() & "');"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", ErrorMessage, True)
        myconn.Close()
    End Try
    myconn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `smd.ExecuteNonQuery`, not `smd.EndExecuteNonQuery`.  The second one is for asynchronous operations.  `EndExecuteNonQuery` expects a parameter, `ExecuteNonQuery` does not.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the ExecuteReader with a ExecuteNonQuery as you are just inserting data.
In you coede, my guess is each time you call ExecuteReader you get a new reader so you should call the close on the first one you created.

Comment: Let me try it. Just a moment

Comment: should I remove `smd.ExecuteReader().Close()` as well?

Comment: should it be `smd.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: when i try to add 'smd.executeNonQuery()` I have a mistake that an argument is missing

Comment: `smd.ExecuteReader().Close()` would probably throw an exception (not sure, as I haven't worked with MySQL).  I would get rid of it, and use `ExecuteNonQuery` like Eduardo suggested.  Post an example of one of your query strings that is giving you the argument is missing error and we can probably tell you what's wrong.